# Ansible: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: json, ansible

The next task reads the contents of a file and for each line read (JSON format), calls a script. This part works fine

```yaml
- name: create users
  script:
    cmd: myscript.sh "{{item}}"
  with_lines: "cat users-list"
```

I'm now trying to add a condition to the script call that depends on the content of the row being read (a field from the JSON being read), but I can't seem to find the correct syntax.

```yaml
- name: create users
  script:
    cmd: myscript.sh "{{item}}"
  with_lines: "cat users-list"
  when: "{{(('{' + item + '}') | from_json).userLogin}}"
```

and I get this error:

> Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

I've tried various syntax, but no luck. I'm a bit out of ideas
Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: [A when close is a jinja2 expression without enclosing curly braces](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when). `when: ('{' ~ item ~'}' | from_json).userLogin is defined`

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of the error is that you need to pass valid JSON to the `from_json` filter, and JSON only supports double quoted strings (`"this is a valid JSON string"`, `'this is not'`).

Additionally, a `when` expression is evaluated in an implicit Jinja template context, which means you never use `{{...}}` template markers in the condition.

Unfortunately, without knowing the format of your `users-list` file, it's hard to suggest the correct syntax. If each line in that file is a valid JSON document, like this:

```
{"username": "bob", "userLogin": true}
{"username": "alice", "userLogin": false}
```

Then you could write your task like this:

```
- name: create users
  script:
    cmd: myscript.sh "{{item}}"
  with_lines: "cat users-list"
  when: "(item|from_json).userLogin"
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply:

The user list format islike this:
'userName': 'abc','userLogin': 'def','userPassword': 'ghi'

Lines from user-list don't include the surrounding { and } characters. This is why I add them to allow json conversion

Comment: Right, but just adding the missing `{` and `}` doesn't make that valid JSON -- as I mentioned in the beginning of my answer, valid JSON requires double quotes. I would update the answer to address this, but the format of your input still isn't clear: is the value of `userLogin` a boolean? Or something else? Is it quoted? Please *update your question* with an example of what your input data looks like, and I would be happy to update this answer.

Comment: Yes sorry. As a result of wanting to simplify the question, I realize I wasn't that clear, neither was complete about what I'm tring to do.

I have 3 scripts: 
One that sends a userLogin (json) as input, and which returns as json if user exists (true/false in result field):
"{\"executionTime\":{\"millis\":48,\"seconds\":0},\"result\":true,\"returnCode\":0}"

Comment: A second one only called if the user doesn't exist yet, that sends userLogin and additionnal properties (json) to create the user

Comment: A third one only called if the user already exists, that sends userLogin and additionnal properties (json) to update the user

Comment: And one file for input data, containing users information:
'username': 'bob', 'userLogin': 'bob@whatever.com', ...
'username': 'alice', 'userLogin': 'alice@whatever.com', ...
...
For some reasons, i don't want to add curly braces and double quotes in the input file
I hope the above is still readable and clearer

Comment: By "update your question", I meant, "click the **edit** link under your question, and add new information there, rather than piling it on in comments". That makes it much easier to read (for example, it's not possible to usefully format code/config sample in comments). Please move the information to the question and delete these comments. Thanks!